# How to remove color from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with green background, for example:

[image]

My purpose is to show everything that is not green

There`s the code to highlight green

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

low_green = np.array([25, 52, 72])
high_green = np.array([102, 255, 255])

while True:
    img = cv2.imread('someimage.jpg')
    img = cv2.resize(img, (900, 650), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # convert BGR to HSV
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # create the Mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, low_green, high_green)

    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("cam", img)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

And mask image
[image]

How do i show everything that is black on mask image?

Comment: If you invert your mask (i.e. `mask = 255 - mask`) and scale it to the range 0..1 (i.e. `mask /= 255`) , the white areas will become `0` and the black areas will become `1`. Multiply your image by that mask and it will become zero (i.e. black) everywhere the mask is currently white and stay as it is (because multiplying by 1 doesn't change anything) everywhere it is currently black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have the green mask, where white is what is green and black what isn't...

So you take the inverse of that mask(black becomes white and white black) and apply such mask on your image.

Answer (score 7):

Here`s the code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

low_green = np.array([25, 52, 72])
high_green = np.array([102, 255, 255])

while True:
    img = cv2.imread('someimage.JPG')
    img = cv2.resize(img, (900, 650), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # convert BGR to HSV
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # create the Mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, low_green, high_green)
    # inverse mask
    mask = 255-mask
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("cam", img)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

and the result[image]